# Mock function from other module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have two python files:

function.py:

```
def foo ():
    return 20

def func ():
    temp = foo()
    return temp
```

and mocking.py:

```
 from testing.function import *
 import unittest
 import mock
 class Testing(unittest.TestCase):

 def test_myTest(self):

     with mock.patch('function.func') as FuncMock:
         FuncMock.return_value = 'string'

         self.assertEqual('string', func())
```

I want to mock func, but with no positive result. I have AssertionError: 'string' != 20. What should I do to mock it correctly ?  If I do mock.patch ('func') I have TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'func'. If I move func to mocking.py and call foo: function.foo() it works correctly. But how to do it when I don't want to move functions from function.py to mocking.py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking is useful when you're calling an actual function but you want some function calls inside that function to be mocked out. In your case you're aiming to mock `func` and you wish to call that mocked function directly by doing `func()`.

However that won't work because you're mocking `function.func` but you've imported `func` already into your test file. So the `func()` that you're calling is an actual function, it's not the same as the mocked `FuncMock`. Try calling `FuncMock()` and you'll get the result as expected.

The following should work and it gives you an idea of what can be done:

```
from testing.function import func
import unittest
import mock

class Testing(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_myTest(self):

        with mock.patch('testing.function.foo') as FooMock:
            FooMock.return_value = 'string'

            self.assertEqual('string', func())
```